# error during execution CI/CD in gitlab for a project

Tags: android, gitlab-ci

I need to configure CI/CD service of gitlab. So, I created a file `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "26"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "26.0.2"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-linux.zip
  - unzip android-sdk.zip
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
  - export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/
```

I need only build an artifact in cloud without testing. So, after commit at master, cd pipeline start execution, and fail. It failed all time on downloading an sdk:

```
.....
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-i386_2.24-11+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-i386 (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lib32z1.
Preparing to unpack .../lib32z1_1%3a1.2.8.dfsg-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lib32z1 (1:1.2.8.dfsg-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lib32gcc1.
Preparing to unpack .../lib32gcc1_1%3a6.3.0-18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lib32gcc1 (1:6.3.0-18) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lib32stdc++6.
Preparing to unpack .../lib32stdc++6_6.3.0-18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lib32stdc++6 (6.3.0-18) ...
Setting up libc6-i386 (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...
Setting up lib32z1 (1:1.2.8.dfsg-5) ...
Setting up lib32gcc1 (1:6.3.0-18) ...
Setting up lib32stdc++6 (6.3.0-18) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...
$ wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-linux.zip
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no variable `ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS` as used in the `wget`, you only have:

- `ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS`
- `ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK`

Comment: Yes, I forgot about it. But when I add this variable like this: 

`variables: 
    ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "26"
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "26.0.2"
    ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "26.0.2"`

It failed on `wget` again 
`$ wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r${ANDROID_SD‌​K_TOOLS}-linux.zip
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1 `

Comment: Please remove the --quiet on the wget and post error

Comment: `--2018-01-02 15:08:33--  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r26.0.2-linux.zip
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 74.125.141.190, 74.125.141.91, 74.125.141.93, ...
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|74.125.141.190|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-01-02 15:08:33 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

I thought about something like this. It turns out that it is impossible to download an Android SDK tools.
So this link is incorrect:
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r26.0.2-linux.zip

Answer (score 0):

The below configuration settings worked for me. It seems that Gitlab has not updated the default .yml file. More details are given in  [Link](https://dev.to/s_anastasov/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects-a6o)

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/
    - .gradle/

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "26"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "26.0.2"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "26.0.2"


before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1

  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip
  - unzip -q android-sdk.zip -d android-sdk-linux

  - mkdir android-sdk-linux/licenses
  - printf "8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55\nd56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e" > android-sdk-linux/licenses/android-sdk-license
  - android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update > update.log
  - android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" "extras;google;m2repository" "extras;android;m2repository" > installPlatform.log

  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/

unitTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew test
```

Comment: thanks, I was try it, please, looks to new answer (in it I place log of this script)

Answer (score -1):

`$ android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update > update.log
Warning: File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.`
`$ android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" "extras;google;m2repository" "extras;android;m2repository" > installPlatform.log`
`Warning: File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.`
`$ export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux`
`$ export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/`
`$ chmod +x ./gradlew`
`$ ./gradlew assembleDebug`
`Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain`
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1